# Deserialize NUnit XML output

Tags: c#, nunit, nunit-3.0

I'm trying to incorporate into a project a custom NUnit (3) test runner.
I'm currently using this kind of code (pulled straight from https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit-engine/Getting-Started.html):

```
var engine = TestEngineActivator.CreateInstance();
var package = new TestPackage("my.test.assembly.dll");
var runner = engine.GetRunner(package);
XmlNode testResult = runner.Run(listener: null, TestFilter.Empty);
```

The code runs fine and I get a test result, in the form of a `test-run` xml node (example at the end of the question).

I expected to find some helper to deserialize this kind of XML in the (quite numerous) NUnit assemblies, but it seems that every single one is treating the data as an XML document, reading and writing single attributes/elements.

Is there some "official" way (e.g. a Nuget package, a framework type, etc) to deserialize this XML into standard model classes?

Example of the result I get:

```
<test-run id="0" name="TestLibrary.Example.dll"
     fullname="...\tests\TestLibrary.Example.dll"
     runstate="Runnable" testcasecount="5" result="Passed" total="5" passed="5" failed="0"
     inconclusive="0" skipped="0" asserts="5" engine-version="3.11.1.0"
     clr-version="4.0.30319.42000" start-time="2023-01-11 13:53:13Z" end-time="2023-01-11 13:53:13Z"
     duration="0.133984">
     <command-line><![CDATA["myexe.exe"]]></command-line>
     <test-suite type="Assembly" id="0-1008" name="TestLibrary.Example.dll"
          fullname="TestLibrary.Example.dll" runstate="Runnable" testcasecount="5" result="Passed"
          start-time="2023-01-11 13:53:13Z" end-time="2023-01-11 13:53:13Z" duration="0.053977"
          total="5" passed="5" failed="0" warnings="0" inconclusive="0" skipped="0" asserts="5">
          <environment framework-version="3.11.0.0" clr-version="4.0.30319.42000"
               os-version="Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.19045.0" platform="Win32NT"
               cwd="..." machine-name="machine"
               user="user" user-domain="domain" culture="it-IT" uiculture="en-US"
               os-architecture="x64" />
          <settings>
               <setting name="ImageRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.30319" />
               <setting name="ImageTargetFrameworkName" value=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
               <setting name="ImageRequiresX86" value="False" />
               <setting name="ImageRequiresDefaultAppDomainAssemblyResolver" value="False" />
               <setting name="RuntimeFramework" value="net-4.0" />
               <setting name="NumberOfTestWorkers" value="16" />
          </settings>
          <properties>
               <property name="_PID" value="8204" />
               <property name="_APPDOMAIN" value="domain-4461bdb5-TestLibrary.Example.dll" />
          </properties>
          <test-suite type="TestSuite" id="0-1009" name="TestLibrary" fullname="TestLibrary"
               runstate="Runnable" testcasecount="5" result="Passed"
               start-time="2023-01-11 13:53:13Z" end-time="2023-01-11 13:53:13Z" duration="0.038980"
               total="5" passed="5" failed="0" warnings="0" inconclusive="0" skipped="0" asserts="5">
               <test-suite type="TestSuite" id="0-1010" name="Example"
                    fullname="TestLibrary.Example" runstate="Runnable" testcasecount="5"
                    result="Passed" start-time="2023-01-11 13:53:13Z"
                    end-time="2023-01-11 13:53:13Z" duration="0.038561" total="5" passed="5"
                    failed="0" warnings="0" inconclusive="0" skipped="0" asserts="5">
                    <test-suite type="TestFixture" id="0-1000" name="ExampleTestFixture"
                         fullname="TestLibrary.Example.ExampleTestFixture"
                         classname="TestLibrary.Example.ExampleTestFixture" runstate="Runnable"
                         testcasecount="5" result="Passed" start-time="2023-01-11 13:53:13Z"
                         end-time="2023-01-11 13:53:13Z" duration="0.035698" total="5" passed="5"
                         failed="0" warnings="0" inconclusive="0" skipped="0" asserts="5">
                         <test-suite type="ParameterizedMethod" id="0-1004" name="ParameterizedTest"
                              fullname="TestLibrary.Example.ExampleTestFixture.ParameterizedTest"
                              classname="TestLibrary.Example.ExampleTestFixture" runstate="Runnable"
                              testcasecount="2" result="Passed" start-time="2023-01-11 13:53:13Z"
                              end-time="2023-01-11 13:53:13Z" duration="0.028787" total="2"
                              passed="2" failed="0" warnings="0" inconclusive="0" skipped="0"
                              asserts="2">
                              <test-case id="0-1002" name="Example1"
                                   fullname="TestLibrary.Example.ExampleTestFixture.Example1"
                                   methodname="ParameterizedTest"
                                   classname="TestLibrary.Example.ExampleTestFixture"
                                   runstate="Runnable" seed="1295788249" result="Passed"
                                   start-time="2023-01-11 13:53:13Z" end-time="2023-01-11 13:53:13Z"
                                   duration="0.022636" asserts="1">
                                   <output><![CDATA[Running ExampleTestFixture.SetupMethod
     Running ExampleTestFixture.ParameterizedTest
     ]]></output>
                              </test-case>
                              <test-case id="0-1003" name="ParameterizedTest(2,3,5)"
                                   fullname="TestLibrary.Example.ExampleTestFixture.ParameterizedTest(2,3,5)"
                                   methodname="ParameterizedTest"
                                   classname="TestLibrary.Example.ExampleTestFixture"
                                   runstate="Runnable" seed="891989160" result="Passed"
                                   start-time="2023-01-11 13:53:13Z" end-time="2023-01-11 13:53:13Z"
                                   duration="0.000241" asserts="1">
                                   <output><![CDATA[Running ExampleTestFixture.SetupMethod
     Running ExampleTestFixture.ParameterizedTest
     ]]></output>
                              </test-case>
                         </test-suite>
                         <test-case id="0-1001" name="SimpleTest"
                              fullname="TestLibrary.Example.ExampleTestFixture.SimpleTest"
                              methodname="SimpleTest"
                              classname="TestLibrary.Example.ExampleTestFixture" runstate="Runnable"
                              seed="202878501" result="Passed" start-time="2023-01-11 13:53:13Z"
                              end-time="2023-01-11 13:53:13Z" duration="0.001015" asserts="1">
                              <output><![CDATA[Running ExampleTestFixture.SetupMethod
     Running ExampleTestFixture.SimpleTest
     ]]></output>
                         </test-case>
                         <test-suite type="ParameterizedMethod" id="0-1007" name="TestWithSource"
                              fullname="TestLibrary.Example.ExampleTestFixture.TestWithSource"
                              classname="TestLibrary.Example.ExampleTestFixture" runstate="Runnable"
                              testcasecount="2" result="Passed" start-time="2023-01-11 13:53:13Z"
                              end-time="2023-01-11 13:53:13Z" duration="0.000261" total="2"
                              passed="2" failed="0" warnings="0" inconclusive="0" skipped="0"
                              asserts="2">
                              <test-case id="0-1005" name="Example1"
                                   fullname="TestLibrary.Example.ExampleTestFixture.Example1"
                                   methodname="TestWithSource"
                                   classname="TestLibrary.Example.ExampleTestFixture"
                                   runstate="Runnable" seed="1768044693" result="Passed"
                                   start-time="2023-01-11 13:53:13Z" end-time="2023-01-11 13:53:13Z"
                                   duration="0.000162" asserts="1">
                                   <output><![CDATA[Running ExampleTestFixture.SetupMethod
     Running ExampleTestFixture.TestWithSource
     ]]></output>
                              </test-case>
                              <test-case id="0-1006" name="TestWithSource(2,3,5)"
                                   fullname="TestLibrary.Example.ExampleTestFixture.TestWithSource(2,3,5)"
                                   methodname="TestWithSource"
                                   classname="TestLibrary.Example.ExampleTestFixture"
                                   runstate="Runnable" seed="858491452" result="Passed"
                                   start-time="2023-01-11 13:53:13Z" end-time="2023-01-11 13:53:13Z"
                                   duration="0.000051" asserts="1">
                                   <output><![CDATA[Running ExampleTestFixture.SetupMethod
     Running ExampleTestFixture.TestWithSource
     ]]></output>
                              </test-case>
                         </test-suite>
                    </test-suite>
               </test-suite>
          </test-suite>
     </test-suite>
</test-run>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No, there are no such classes availble.

NUnit itself never makes use of it's XML output. It's just that: output. In fact, it's considered the primary output from your test run and contains all the info available about each test.

The NUnit documentation contains information about the format of this output (see https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/technical-notes/usage/Test-Result-XML-Format.html) but it may not be completely up to date.

Essentially, the NUnit team has drawn a boundary around the project, leaving the interpretation of the XML result up to the user. Many programs, both open and closed source, make use of the XML result to provide different kinds of output. Someone could create the kind of system you ask about, providing a set of model classes to represent the test run, but I'm not aware of anyone who has published such a system.

Note that you can, if you wish, integrate your own code to re-format or display the content of the XML file with the engine by writing an engine extension. The `IResultWriter` extension point exists for this purpose. See https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit-engine/extensions/creating-extensions/Result-Writers.html

Answer (score 1):

Well, following the advice from Charlie Poole I created my own deserialization types. In case one day someone else should have the same necessity, I'm pasting here my work in progress:

```
public enum RunState
{
    NotRunnable,
    Runnable,
    Explicit,
    Skipped,
    Ignored
}

public enum TestResult
{
    Inconclusive,
    Passed,
    Warning,
    Skipped,
    Failed,
    Error
}

[Serializable, XmlRoot("test-run", IsNullable = false)]
public class TestRun
{
    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("fullname")]
    public string Fullname { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("runstate")]
    public RunState RunState { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("testcasecount")]
    public int TestCaseCount { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("result")]
    public TestResult Result { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("total")]
    public int Total { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("passed")]
    public int Passed { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("failed")]
    public int Failed { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("inconclusive")]
    public int Inconclusive { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("skipped")]
    public int Skipped { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("asserts")]
    public int Asserts { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("engine-version")]
    public string EngineVersion { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("clr-version")]
    public string ClrVersion { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("start-time")]
    public string StartTime { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("end-time")]
    public string EndTime { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("duration")]
    public decimal Duration { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("command-line")]
    public string CommandLine { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("test-suite", typeof(TestSuite))]
    public List<TestSuite> Tests { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("filter")]
    public XmlNode Filter { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class TestBase
{
    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("fullname")]
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("runstate")]
    public RunState RunState { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("result")]
    public TestResult Result { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("start-time")]
    public string StartTime { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("end-time")]
    public string EndTime { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("duration")]
    public decimal Duration { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("asserts")]
    public int Asserts { get; set; }

    [XmlArray(ElementName = "properties"), XmlArrayItem("property", typeof(NameValuePair), IsNullable = false)]
    public List<NameValuePair> Properties { get; set; }

    [XmlArray(ElementName = "assertions"), XmlArrayItem("assertion", typeof(TestAssertion), IsNullable = false)]
    public List<TestAssertion> Assertions { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("output")]
    public string Output { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("reason")]
    public TestReason Reason { get; set; }
}

public class TestFailure
{
    [XmlElement("message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("stack-trace")]
    public string StackTrace { get; set; }
}

public class TestAssertion
{
    [XmlAttribute("result")]
    public TestResult Result { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("stack-trace")]
    public string StackTrace { get; set; }
}

public class TestReason
{
    [XmlElement("message")]
    public List<string> Messages { get; set; }
}

[Serializable, XmlRoot("test-suite")]
public class TestSuite : TestBase
{
    [XmlAttribute("testcasecount")]
    public int TestCaseCount { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("total")]
    public int Total { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("passed")]
    public int Passed { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("failed")]
    public int Failed { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("warnings")]
    public int Warnings { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("inconclusive")]
    public int Inconclusive { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("skipped")]
    public int Skipped { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("environment", typeof(TestEnvironment))]
    public TestEnvironment Environment { get; set; }

    [XmlArray(ElementName = "settings"), XmlArrayItem("setting", typeof(NameValuePair), IsNullable = false)]
    public List<NameValuePair> Settings { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("test-suite", typeof(TestSuite))]
    [XmlElement("test-case", typeof(TestCase))]
    public List<TestBase> Tests { get; set; }
}

[Serializable, XmlRoot("test-case")]
public class TestCase : TestBase
{
    [XmlAttribute("methodname")]
    public string MethodName { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("classname")]
    public string ClassName { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("seed")]
    public long Seed { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("label")]
    public string Label { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("site")]
    public string Site { get; set; } = "Test";
}

[Serializable]
public class TestEnvironment
{
    [XmlAttribute("framework-version")]
    public string FrameworkVersion { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("clr-version")]
    public string ClrVersion { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("os-version")]
    public string OsVersion { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("platform")]
    public string Platform { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("cwd")]
    public string Cwd { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("machine-name")]
    public string MachineName { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("user")]
    public string User { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("user-domain")]
    public string UserDomain { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("culture")]
    public string Culture { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("uiculture")]
    public string UiCulture { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("os-architecture")]
    public string OsArchitecture { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class NameValuePair
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Except (at least) for the `Filter` property of the `TestRun`, which is out of scope for my needs and has a pretty complex (i.e. nested) structure, it seems to work well enough. For sure there are a lot of possible improvements (proper date parsing, as an example), but it's very easy to use:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TestRun));

using (var stringReader = new StringReader(testResult.OuterXml))
{
    var testrun = (TestRun) serializer.Deserialize(stringReader);
}
```

I have yet to unit test every single property, but is seems to be already a pretty good bootstrap for anyone else attempting this task.